Efficient pooling to extract global embedding from local features (for LiDAR point clouds)
Problem:
I have 3d point cloud data (autonomous driving setting) and a point cloud encoder (MinkUNet) that extracts local features from them. What are suitable pooling techniques to map those local (pointwise) features to a global embedding for the whole point cloud?
To be more precise, I have:
Input: Tensor of size (batch_size, #points, 4)
Local features: Tensor of size (batch_size, #points, 96)

And I want:
Global feature embeddings: Tensor of size (batch_size, embed_dim)

In the end, I want to match the point cloud embeddings to embeddings obtained from other modalities (e.g. images). The embedding dimension embed_dim will probably be something between 256 and 512 while the number of points #points (actually the max over the batch) is usually in the thousands.
I have limited experience in computer vision and no experience in 3d. My intuition is that simply pooling (avg or max) the point cloud features to the given feature dimenson of 96 and then linearly projecting that to the higher embedding dimension will lose too much information -- that is the approach that I would use for images though.
One idea I can think of is projecting the local features to local embeddings first with a projection matrix that is shared among all points, then use a simple avg/max pooling to obtain the global embedding.
Another idea would be to learn a weight for each of the 96 features to represent their relevance, then apply standard pooling and project to the embedding space.
The first method seems more expressive intuitively, but it involves a matrix-vector product for each point while the latter seems more simple and involves only pointwise operations.
I also learned that there is something like attention pooling, but I don't quite understand how that would work.
What are suitable methods to achieve a good representation and stay computationally efficient?
